# Cloning a viewer material

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to override the color of a component in the viewer, in order to conserve the same rendering effect than other components I would like to clone an existing material and simply modify the color of the clone.

I can change the color of an existing material as follow:

```
var renderProxy =
  viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(
    model, fragIds[0])

renderProxy.material.setHex(0xFF0000)
```

This affects all other components in the model which are using that material, which is not the desired result.

For that purpose I would like to clone material, modify it and affect the new material to a specific component. Invoking the material.clone() method is working:

```
var newMat = renderProxy.material.clone()
newMat.setHex(0xFF0000)
```

But the new material will loose all the specific properties that makes it look nice by the renderer.

So my question "is there a way to -easily- clone a viewer material without writing the cloning code for each property"?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to clone the 'prism' material, rather than the 3js phong-material.

Start with this repo: https://github.com/wallabyway/fusion-chair-configurator

as an example, to create a 'metal' material, use these two lines of code (and copy the initPaint() function).

https://github.com/wallabyway/fusion-chair-configurator/blob/c6d5bd575cdf40194c9fbdd1c5f9bb27c70b356e/docs/js/app.js#L107-L108

The szPrism json string, contains lots of parameters.  Prism materials are rather complex, but you can find out more about what these parameters do by understanding this article for the Autodesk Cloud Render ART help page (the real-time renderer built inside Revit2019, Fusion360, etc)...

http://help.autodesk.com/view/ARENDERING/ENU/?guid=GUID-49345267-CE6A-4006-BB58-5BEAFD8B0D0E

Try experimenting with Fusion360's 'render' mode. Start by opening 'appearance' and creating some custom materials. You can modify their parameters in real-time to better understand what they do and get the effect you are looking for.

Here is a tutorial video on Fusion360 custom materials:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9AS5rQhtPo

Let me know if that helps.

[image]